# How do I replace each item, without changing array's structure?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
```

How do I run `foreach` for this array and write updated value to its place?

Like:

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
   // do something
   // replace old value of this item with a new one
}
```

---

Example:

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (item == 'lastname')
        $item = 'firstname';
        // replace current $item's value with a 'firstname'
}
```

Array should become:

```
$array = array('firstname', 'email', 'phone');
```

Comment: You can also try 
 <?php
function myfunction(&$value,$key)
{
  if (value== 'lastname')
        $value= 'firstname';
}
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');

array_walk($array ,"myfunction");
print_r($a);
?>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative is to loop by reference:

```
foreach ($array as &$value) {
    $value = strtoupper($value);
}
unset($value);// <=== majorly important to NEVER forget this line after looping by reference...
```

Comment: what is **&** for, inside "&$value"?

Comment: can you describe in two words? that page is too big

Comment: 2 words? There is a _reason_ the page is big. In short: 2 or more variable names (in this case `$array[<particular key>]` and `$item`) will point to the same value in memory, `unset()`ing one will keep the value intact for the other, changing one will mean the other will have the same changed data.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, a foreach loop would seem unnecessary if you know exactly what key maps to `lastname`, but if you need to you can still loop through the values. There are two very common ways: set the value according to the key:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == 'lastname') {
        $array[$key] = 'firstname';
    }
}
```

Or (PHP 5 only) use references:

```
foreach ($array as &$item) {
    if ($item == 'lastname') {
        $item = 'firstname';
    }
}

// Clean up the reference variable
unset($item);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
   $array[$key] = "updated item";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
    if ($value == 'lastname')
        $array[$i] = 'firstname';
}
```